# Why is sys time 0 here?

Tags: linux, time, kernel, sleep, context-switch

When I do `$(time sleep 1)`, I got:

```
real    0m1.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I'm not sure why `sys` time was 0, so `nanosleep` is called from userspace ?

Also, does the real time equals to context switch time + real sleep time (1s) ?

Comment: Those are rounded, run it a few hundred times and you'll see slightly different times. (Time spent sleeping doesn't get accounted, it's not CPU time unless it's a busy-loop which isn't a real sleep.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [man page for time](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time), we can see that,

1. **real** : Length of time the program took to terminate, calculated as :

   > `(time at end of program - time at star of program)`
2. **user** : The sum of the tms_utime and tms_cutime values in a struct tms as returned by times(2)
3. **sys** : The sum of the tms_stime and tms_cstime values in a struct tms as returned by times(2)

So the result you are getting effectively means that your program lasted for 1 second and in that 1 second it used 0 seconds as user time and 0 seconds as system time. Which is exactly what we should expect from the program.

When a program is sleeping it just means the kernel will not schedule it for processing, it won't even run no-ops, it just wont run so no system time is consumed.

Answer (score 6):

Because the process is not executing kernel-space code while it is sleeping. The kernel is executing other processes, or idling, neither of which is influenced by the sleeping process.